# SKIP not working at the beginning of the line

Tags: javacc

having this

`|83.56|
|as.63|
|as.lk|
|as45.34|`

as imput in a *.txt file i need to skip the character "|" in the beginning but also at the end of the line, cause the output should be

`<83.56> :only numbers
<as.63> 
<as.lk> :only letters
<as45.34> :numers/letters together`

i got this as my code declaration 
[whitout "|" at the beggining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu2HX.png) 
and nothing appears as result, this is strange cause if i put the character "|" by this [way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5micR.png) the result its almost the expected one, its this 
`<|83.56> :only numbers
<|as.63> 
<|as.lk> :only letters
<|as45.34> :numers/letters together`
so the matter is that the "|" of the end of the line it´s being skipped propertly, but the one at the beginning don´t

note: I have also declared at the beginning numeros and letras_minusculas, by this way

```
TOKEN:{<Numeros:["0"-"9"]>}
TOKEN:{<Letras_minusculas:["a"-"z"]>}
```

Comment: Can you supply a complete and minimal failing example, please? Supply a complete .jj file and at least one input string that is not tokenized as you would like.

Comment: thanks for it @TheodoreNorvell i could do it, it was just to put some TOKENS in private, when i realise of that it works perfectly, but again thanks for all

Comment: Good.  The best solutions are the ones you discover yourself.

Answer (score 0):

JavaCC has provided a skip section where the un-necessary characters are skipped.

Please find the example skip block below.

```
SKIP : {
   "|"
}
TOKEN : {
<NUMERIC: ["0"-"9","."]+ >
<ALPHA : ["a"-"b","."]+ >
<ALPHA-NUM : ((NUMERIC>|<ALPHA>))+ >
}
```

sample inputs:

```
|83.56| --> NUMERIC without "|"
|as.63| --> ALPHA-NUM without "|"
|as.lk| --> ALPHA without "|"
|as45.34| --> ALPHA-NUM without "|"
```

note the skip will not skip the characters when any possible match already started.

Eg : |83|3.56|

*The character "83" will be started to match `NUMERIC` and `ALPHA-NUM` so the next character cannot be skipped. Here in our case causes the error, Because all the possible match is not accommodating the `"|"` symbol.*

*If we changed the rule like below.*

```
SKIP : {
   "|"
}
TOKEN : {
<NUMERIC: ["0"-"9","."]+ >
<ALPHA : ["a"-"b","."]+ >
<ALPHA-NUM : ((NUMERIC>|<ALPHA>|"|"))+ >
}
```

Then the input matches to `ALPHA-NUM` including `"|"` i.e.: `83|3.56`